# How do I get my USB 3 ExpressCard to work after suspend?

Tags: usb, suspend, thinkpad, expresscard

I have a problem with a USB 3.0 ExpressCard. When I close my ThinkPad X200, it suspends and after I open it back up, the USB ports on said expresscard are no longer working. Is there a kernel or BIOS option that could fix this?